Finishing the proof of the triangle inequality of Hausdorff metric
currently I am trying to show that a certain type of Hausdorff metric satisfies the following triangle equality and I am stuck.
Setup:

Take $(X,d)$ as metric space.
Denote by $C(X)$ the set of closed sets off $(X,d)$.
I want to define the Hausdorff metric of closed sets $D \colon C(X) \times C(X) \to [0,\infty)$ as follows
$$
D(A,B) = \inf\{ \epsilon > 0 \colon A \subseteq B_{\epsilon} \text { and } B\subseteq A_{\epsilon}\},
$$
where $A_{\epsilon} = \{x \in X \colon d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$

Claim: $$D(A,B) \leq D(A,C) + D(C,B)$$ for all $A,B,C \in C(X)$.
Proof/Attempt: Take an arbitary $\widetilde{\epsilon} > 0$, by definition of $D$ there exists $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \geq 0$ such that
$$
D(A,C) + \widetilde{\epsilon}/2 > \epsilon_1 \quad \text{ and } D(B,C) + \widetilde{\epsilon}/2 > \epsilon_2.
$$
Now adding both terms together we achieve the desired inequality if we are able to show that
$$
D(A,B) < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2.
$$
It sufficies to show that $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ is an upper bound for $D(A,B)$. Thus take any $\delta \geq 0$ such that
$$
A \subseteq B_{\delta} \quad \text{ and } \quad B \subseteq A_{\delta},
$$
we need to show that $\delta \leq \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ and this is a bit where I am stuck.
Ideas: Formally it would be enough to show that
$$B_{\delta} \subseteq B_{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2},$$
since then the above inequality holds. Thus take any $b \in B_{\delta}$ one needs to show that $b \in B_{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}$ and this is the case iff $d(b,B) \leq \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$, so in the end we need to get an estimate of the form
$$
d(b,B) \leq \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2.
$$
Generally if $A \subseteq B$ then $d(a,B) \leq d(a,C)$ by definition. Now since $B \subseteq C_{\epsilon_2}$ there exists some $c_2 \in C \colon d(c_2,B) < \epsilon_2$ and also since $A \subseteq C_{\epsilon_1}$ there exists some $c_1 \in C \colon d(c_1,A) < \epsilon_1$, I would like to use the estimate
$$
d(b,B) \leq d(c_1,A) + d(c_2,B),
$$
but this looks incorrect. Can you give me some hints?

Missing a $ at the end of the setup. Tried to make this edit, but edits can’t be this short.

You cannot use any $\delta$ in the argument you outlined. I think your method can work. For completeness I attempt a proof below.
Let $r,s$ be such that
$$ A\subseteq B_r, B\subseteq A_r\text{ and } B\subseteq C_s, C\subseteq B_s.$$
Let $a\in A.$ Since $a\in B_r$, then $d(a,B)<r$, since $0<r-d(a,B)$, there is a $b\in B$, such that $d(a,b)<r.$ Similarly, since $b\in C_s$, there is a $c\in C$, such that $d(b,c)<s$. Hence,
$$ d(a,c)\leq d(x,b) + d(b,c) < r+s, $$ so $a\in C_{r+s}$. This shows $A\subseteq C_{r+s}.$ Similarly, $C\subseteq A_{r+s}.$
Consequently, $$\{t:A\subseteq C_t,C\subseteq A_t\} \supseteq \{r+s: A\subseteq B_r, B\subseteq A_r\text{ and } B\subseteq C_s, C\subseteq B_s\}.$$ Taking the infimum over $t$, then over $r,s$, shows $D(A,C)\leq D(A,B)+D(B,C).$

You wrote that I cannot use any delta in my proof but considering your answer it seems that your $t$ is exactly $\delta$ in my proof? Also the method used method is different, instead of trying to show the set-inclusion by $\delta$ one shows that any values of $r,s$ such that one has the corresponding setinclusions of $A,B,C$ implies that for the sum $r+s$ one has  at least $A \subseteq C_t$ and $C \subseteq A_t$, and so the method is different but preferable better? Why did you choose this way other the other?

If $\delta$ is arbitrary, it can be arbitrarily large, in particular larger than $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$. That’s the reason I reversed the order and showed $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$ is a possible $\delta$. In any case, I felt I used the same basic idea. At first I thought about using $\left(A_s\right)t \subset A{s+t}$. But couldn’t immediately make it work. I changed the notation to $r,s,t$ since it is easier to type.
